# Efficiently extract fitted values from linear regression with many groups

Tags: r

How can I efficiently extract the fitted values from several linear regression models and append them to the original data used to build the models?

Example Data:

```
library(dplyr)

# Fit several (3 in this case) linear regression models 

fitted_models <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(model = lm(Petal.Length~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data = .))
```

I can extract the fitted values for each group (see below) but this is cumbersome and would be inefficient if you have 10's or 100's of models. How can I more efficiently extract the fitted data from the models and append them back to the dataset used to build the models?

```
df2 <- iris[,c(5,3)]
df2$predicted <- NA
df2[1:50,3] <- fitted_models$model[[1]]$fitted.values
df2[51:100,3] <- fitted_models$model[[2]]$fitted.values 
df2[101:150,3] <- fitted_models$model[[3]]$fitted.values 
df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting used to nested data frames can be helpful for things like this. Here is one approach for your entire problem.

You can find more examples here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

fitted_models <- iris %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = .x)),
         fitted.values = map(fit, "fitted.values")) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data, fitted.values)) %>% 
  select(-fit)
```

```r
> fitted_models
# A tibble: 150 x 6
   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width fitted.values
   <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2          1.47
 2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2          1.46
 3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2          1.42
 4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2          1.41
 5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2          1.46
 6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4          1.51
 7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3          1.40
 8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2          1.46
 9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2          1.38
10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1          1.45
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: This works well when the data do not have `NA` values. Any way to get it to work when the dependent variable has `NA` values? For example`df <- iris` `df[c(1:2,51:52,101:102),1] <- NA`  `fitted_models <- df %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = .x)),
         fitted.values = map(fit, "fitted.values")) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data, fitted.values)) %>% 
  select(-fit)` When `NA` is present in dependent variable the error message `Error: Incompatible lengths: 50, 48.` gets thrown.

Comment: Could you somehow apply the coefficients from each `Species` model to the original data used to build each `Species` model?

Comment: @tassones what would you expect with NA's? I would filter them out and join them back in at the end, personally. And for your second question can you clarify? This is using the model from each group to predict that said group. Did you want something else?

Comment: I just realized that my first comment has a typo. It should be `df[c(1:2,51:52,101:102),3] <- NA`. I would expect that if I have all the independent data needed to calculate a predicted value then the predicted value would still be calculated even if the dependent variable was `NA`.

Comment: For example, if I do `models_fit <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(model = lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = .))` I can get the model coefficients (at least for one group) with `models_fit[[2]][[1]]$coefficients`. If I could somehow apply those coefficients to the input data then I could get predicted values.

Comment: Yes. Do not do the last `select(-fit)` line in the pipe. The list column "fit" has the model fit for each grouping. So you can do `fitted_models$fit[[2]]` and grab that second fit model. I think you are mixing a few questions at this point. How to predict off the groups with different data.

Comment: [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888088/how-can-i-apply-linear-model-coefficients-to-input-data-for-multiple-groups/70889127#70889127) asks the question in a more direct way and an answer is provided.

Comment: @tassones yes I would have suggested something similar. Glad you got what you need! My one comment is you don't actually need to create that `f` if you didn't want to. You could use `predict()` directly in the map.

Answer (score 3):

With the model created, there is `rowwise` grouping, so we can directly extract in a `list` and `unnest` the list column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
fitted_models %>%
    transmute(Species, fitted.values = list(model$fitted.values)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    unnest(fitted.values)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 150 × 2
   Species fitted.values
   <fct>           <dbl>
 1 setosa           1.47
 2 setosa           1.46
 3 setosa           1.42
 4 setosa           1.41
 5 setosa           1.46
 6 setosa           1.51
 7 setosa           1.40
 8 setosa           1.46
 9 setosa           1.38
10 setosa           1.45
# … with 140 more rows
```